# __callback was called after the specified delay

Tags: solidity, oracles, mocha

My smart contract should return the ETH rate from Coinbase api .. So i'm using Provable engine and i'm testing my smart contract locally using ganache and ethereum-bridge .
It's expected that result should be returned using an event that will be fired whenever the provable call the __callback function of my contract.
To test my contract i'm using mocha-js , but the problem is that my test always finish before the __callback function is called .
In my test i tried to use `callback function(done())`, `promises` and `async / await` but no one of them solved the problem .

this is my contract code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./provableAPI_0.5.sol";

contract eth_rate is usingProvable {
  string public ETHUSD;
   event LogConstructorInitiated(string nextStep);
   event LogPriceUpdated(string price);
   event LogNewProvableQuery(string description);

   constructor() public {
       emit LogConstructorInitiated("Constructor was initiated. Call 'updatePrice()' to send the Provable Query.");
   }

   function __callback(bytes32  myid, string memory result) public {
       if (msg.sender != provable_cbAddress()) revert();
        ETHUSD = result;
        emit LogPriceUpdated(result);
   }

   function updatePrice()public  payable {
       if (provable_getPrice("URL") > msg.sender.balance) {
           emit LogNewProvableQuery("Provable query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
       } else {
           emit LogNewProvableQuery("Provable query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
           provable_query("URL", "json(https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).price");
       }
   }
}
```

and this is my test code:

```js
const eth_rate = artifacts.require("eth_rate");
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
require('truffle-test-utils').init();

contract('eth_rate',  (accounts) => {
    let instance;

     beforeEach('should setup the contract instance', async () => {
         instance = await eth_rate.deployed();
    });

   it("should return the list of accounts", async ()=> {
    console.log(accounts);
  });


 it('ETH rate ', async function() {
  const result = await instance.updatePrice();
  truffleAssert.eventEmitted(result, 'LogPriceUpdated');

  })

});
```

Comment: The callback is not fired immediately, so you will have to wait until it is fired.

Answer (score 1):

I used `setTimeout` function  to wait for the callback transaction.
However setting a timeout might require me to wait longer then necessary .. any way it works for me now and here is my test code :

```js
const eth_rate = artifacts.require("eth_rate");
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
require('truffle-test-utils').init();

contract('eth_rate',  (accounts) => {
    let instance;

     beforeEach('should setup the contract instance', async () => {
         instance = await eth_rate.deployed();
    });

   it("should return the list of accounts", async ()=> {
    console.log(accounts);
  });

  it("ETH rate", function(done) {
    var result;
    eth_rate.deployed().then(function(value) {
      instance = value;
      return instance.updatePrice();
    }).then(function(res){
      result = res;
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 15000));
    }).then(function(){
      return instance.ETHUSD();
    }).then(function(value){
      console.log(" Ethereum rate(USD) = " + value);
      done();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Another possibility is to subscribe to `LogPriceUpdated` event and wait for it to be fired.

Comment: i tried to do that but i think that since the event is fired by an other contract i couldn't catch it so i had to save the result in a var ..